# OpenMp parallelization region calls a subroutine which also calls a subroutine

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, openmp, subroutine

My code works well without parallelization. But it doesn't with parallelization.
My code consists of a module that contains an array of size 100x100x100.

```
real(8), dimension(1:100,1:100,1:100) :: array
```

This module is placed at the lower hierarchical level so it can be called by any other module. And then the other module that consists of a do loop which calls a subroutine.

```
do i=1,100
  do j=1,100
    do k=1,100
      call some_calculation(i,j,k)
    enddo
  enddo
enddo
```

The subroutine some_calculation performs some arithmetic process using the array(i,j,k) and then update array(i,j,k). The input values i,j,k correspond to accessing array(i,j,k). But when I parallelize the most outer do loop

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO 
do i=1,100
  do j=1,100
    do k=1,100
      call some_calculation(i,j,k)
    enddo
  enddo
enddo
!$OMP END PARALLE DO
```

I receive different results of array. Does anyone has any clue for this? Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Your loop indices should be private:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO private (i,j,k)
do i=1,100
   do j=1,100
      do k=1,100
         call some_calculation(i,j,k)
      enddo
   enddo
enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, only `j` and `k` have to be explicitly declared private. `i` is predetermined to be private.

Comment: Actually, none of them has to be private.